# best way to create response curves for a GLM species distribution model in R?

Tags: r, glm

I'm running a binomial GLM to predict the probability of a species occurrence, where I am training on one dataset and testing the model on another dataset:

```
TrainingData<-read.csv("TrainingData.csv")[,-1]
TrainingData[,1]<-as.factor(TrainingData[,1])
TrainingData[,4]<-as.factor(TrainingData[,4])

TestData<-read.csv("TestData.csv")[,-1]
TestData[,1]<-as.factor(TestData[,1])
TestData[,4]<-as.factor(TestData[,4])

mod<-glm(presence~var1+var2+var3, family=binomial, data=TrainingData)

probs=predict(mod, TestData, type="response")
```

What is the best way (or function) to create response curves to plot the relationship between the probability of presence and each predictor variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it would be pretty difficult to help without a reproducible example. It also sounds like the cross validation is unrelated to your question. Try simplifying and sharing sample data.

Comment: I think it would be more typical to estimate based on the x+y projections and then to use a topographic map as a layer upon which you plotted "presence". Furthermore it would be unlikely that the density would be a linear function of the x and y coordinates, so you might instead want to do a 2D kernel density estimation rather than the model you propose.

Comment: What do x, y, and z stand for in this context? Are they spatial coordinates as @BondedDust suggested, or 3 separate predictor variables ignoring spatial coordinates?

Comment: @JimM. none of the variables are lat or lon. They are all environmental variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal probabilities can be calculated from predict.glm with type = "terms",
since each of the terms are calculated with the remaining variables set at their mean values.
This is converted back to a probabilty scale with plogis(term + intercept).

Second, because your data set contains and combination of continuous values and factors 
for your predictor variables, separate plots were made for each type and combined
with grid.arrange.

Although this answers your question directly based on the glm model you presented,
 I would still recommend examining the spatial autocorrelation of both your predictor
 and response variables, as this could have a likely impact on your final model.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

TrainingData <- read.csv("~/Downloads/TrainingData.csv", header = TRUE)
TrainingData[['presence']] <- as.factor(TrainingData[['presence']])
TrainingData[['var3']] <- as.factor(TrainingData[['var3']])
TrainingData[['X']] <- NULL # Not used in the model

TestData <- read.csv("~/Downloads/TestData.csv", header = TRUE)
TestData[['presence']] <- as.factor(TestData[['presence']])
TestData[['var3']] <- as.factor(TestData[['var3']])
TestData[['X']] <- NULL
```

Presence/Absence model

```
mod <- glm(presence ~ var1 + var2 + var3, family = binomial, data = TrainingData)
```

Get predicted probabilities for each of the centered variables (i.e remaining variables set to their mean).

```
mod_terms <- predict(mod, newdata = TestData, type = "terms")
mod_prob <- data.frame(idx = 1:nrow(TestData), plogis(mod_terms + 
    attr(mod_terms, "constant")))
mod_probg <- mod_prob %>% gather(variable, probability, -idx)
```

Melt the Test data into long format

```
TestData['idx'] <- 1:nrow(TestData) # Add index to data
TestData[['X']] <- NULL # Drop the X variable since it was not used in the model

data_long <- melt(TestData, id = c("presence","idx"))

data_long[['value']] <- as.numeric(data_df[['value']])
```

Merge Testdata with predictions and separate the data containing continuous (var1 and var2) and factors (var3).

```
# Merge Testdata with predictions
data_df <- merge(data_long, mod_probg, by = c("idx", "variable"))
data_df <- data_df %>% arrange(variable, value) 

data_continuous <- data_df %>% filter(., variable != "var3") %>% 
    transform(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% arrange(variable, value) 

data_factor <- data_df %>% filter(., variable == "var3") %>%
    transform(value = as.factor(value))%>% 
   arrange(idx)
```

ggplot output

```
g_continuous <- ggplot(data_continuous, aes(x = value, y = probability)) + geom_point()+
 facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x") 

g_factor <-  ggplot(data = data_factor, aes(x = value, y = probability)) + geom_boxplot() +
facet_wrap(~variable) 

grid.arrange(g_continuous, g_factor, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: this is great but I am getting some warnings after melt (attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped). I think it's because var3 is a factor. I have added my dataset above. Can I ignore this or how can I account for this. Thanks!!

Comment: I've made changes to account that var3 is a factor, and have plotted var1 and var2 separately.