# Graphing predicted probabilites for all variables in glmer

Tags: r

I have a glm with random factors fit to binomial (presence/absence) data):

```
nb.canopy <- glmer(case ~ n_hab + canopy.closure + (1|site), data=n.points, family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

I want to make a graph like the one pictured for the variables `n_hab` and `canopy.closure`.
[image]

I've tried starting the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915628/best-way-to-create-response-curves-for-a-glm-species-distribution-model-in-r?rq=1), but when I try

```
mod_terms <- predict(nb.canopy, newdata=n.points, type='terms')
```

I get the error `Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”`. And at any rate, I pretty quickly got lost with that example! This seems like it should be a pretty simple and common type of graph to make, but I've had trouble finding good examples. Any help?

Comment: These are added variable plots?  You could try the **effects** package.  Also I've had students use and like the **ggeffects** package.

Comment: you should explain what the graph that you are trying to reproduce shows.  are they marginal effects?  what are the dotted lines?  confidence intervals?  with or without random effects?